# How to parse dates to get the year in Python

Tags: python, date

I have a bunch of dates from a csv file in this format

```
1/25/2015 1:51
1/26/2015 11:22
1/26/2015 20:33
1/27/2015 15:29
1/28/2015 19:11
1/28/2015 19:41
1/30/2015 6:20
2/2/2015 16:24
2/4/2015 18:38
```

Is there an efficient proper way in Python to parse the date and extract the year?
    2/8/2015 22:22

Comment: Downvoting for the reason "this question does not show any research effort".

Comment: I'd try google with "python parse date".

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler my apologies, you are correct. I did a quick search but found nothing obvious. I was lazy. I won't do that again in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
time.strptime("2/8/2015 22:22", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: Do you mean `datetime`?

Comment: It wouldn't work. It said `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'`. I got it working using `datetime`

Comment: Probably a Python 2/3 thing then.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), an open source library providing high-performance, easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools for the Python programming language.

In particular, look at [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) which allows you to read from a csv file.